# Only one model statement is allowed in a file sending email

Tags: c#, .net

I tried to send an email with System.Net.Mail and a file as a template, my view has this code

```
@using System.Globalization;

@{
    Layout = null;
}

@model myModel

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    @*<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />*@
    @*<title></title>*@
    prop1: @model.prop1<br/>
    prop2: @model.prop2<br/>
    prop3: @model.prop3<br/>
    prop4: @model.prop4<br/>
    prop5: @model.prop5<br />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But when run in a webjob, it throws the following error " Only one model statement is allowed in a file "

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `@Model`, not `@model` to access your model instance.

`@model` should only be called once to define the type of your model.

Replace

```
prop1: @model.prop1<br/>
```

with

```
prop1: @Model.prop1<br/>
```